# Is there an else statement for throw exceptions?

Tags: javascript, throw

I'm new to JavaScript, but not new to programming/scripting in general and I have a query about `throw` exceptions.

So, what I want to know is there a sort of `else` statement for `throw` exceptions.

E.g

```
// More code above
try
{
    if(i=="something") {
        throw "'i' equals 'something'."
    }
    else
    {
        throw "'i' doesn't equal 'something'."
    }
}
// More code here
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: [totally](http://jsbin.com/oxitab/1/edit)

Comment: What about finally block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `finally` keyword

```
try
{
    if(i=="something") {
        throw "'i' equals 'something'."
    }
    else
    {
        throw "'i' doesn't equal 'something'."
    }
} catch( ex ) {
    // your exception handling code
} finally {
    // Statements that are executed after the try statement completes.
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7y6Hz/